# the problem is with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

am facing the issue with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

the following versions i am using

```
powermock-core-1.6.6
powermock-mockito-release-full-1.4.9-full
powermock-api-mockito-1.5.1
junit-4.12
```

when i run my test cases am getting the following errors

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.Uid. Reason: 3
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:284)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:111)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at javassist.bytecode.ByteArray.write16bit(ByteArray.java:40)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Shifter.update(StackMapTable.java:744)
    at
```

My Test Class

```
@PrepareForTest({UUID.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class Uid extends AbstractMuleContextTestCase{
Sample obj=new Sample(); // created obj for actual class
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {  
    String uuidInStr = "3dd4fa6e-2899-4429-b818-d34fe8df5dd0"; 
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(UUID.class);
    PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).thenReturn(uuidInStr.toString());
}
@Test
public void runTestCases() throws Exception{
    LinkedList<CaseInsensitiveHashMap> payload=new LinkedList<CaseInsensitiveHashMap>();
    CaseInsensitiveHashMap map=new CaseInsensitiveHashMap();
    payload.add(map);
    MuleEvent event=getTestEvent(payload,muleContext);
    MuleEventContext eventContext=new DefaultMuleEventContext(event);
    eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("apiKey", "sdsdsa-asdas-asd-asd-asd", PropertyScope.SESSION);     
    eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("clientid", "client", PropertyScope.SESSION);     
    Assert.assertEquals("",obj.onCall(eventContext));   
 }
}
```

how to resolve it? am i making any mistakes in my test cases?

is there any solution? how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason to use multiple versions of PowerMock? Have you checked if those versions are compatible with each other?

Comment: Check if the version of javassist in your classpath is compatible with the PowerMock version you are using. It could be that some other library is specifying different javassist version.

Comment: can you delete all code from runTestCases and use Assert.equals(4, 2+2),just to Check whether class is successfully compiled oot not.

Comment: yeah i did. its not working. still showing the same issue.

Comment: ngueno@ no. i tried to use the same version of jars as well. but still showing the same issue.

Comment: am finding hard to find the right combination. anyone of you know the right combination?

Answer (score 0):

use these combination

```
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.1
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: yeah.. am still getting the same error. as requested, i have added my test class.